# Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I would like you to review on my sample Wordpress theme index.php code.

```
<?php
/*
Template name: Homepage
*/
get_header();
?>
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['action'])):
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        switch($action){
            case "sendmail": include("sendmail.php"); break;
            case "mailsent" : include("thanks.php"); break;
        }
    else:
?>
    <!-------// Begin Content ---------->
    <?php if (have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="contentarea">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <p> <?php the_content(); ?></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="contentarea">
                <h1>Page not Found!</h1>
                <p>Sorry, you are looking a page that is not here! </p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?> 
        <!-------// End Content ----------> 
        <tr>
        <!--begin contact form -->  
            <td class="contactarea" height="200">
                <?php include("contact_area.php"); ?>
            </td>
        <!--end contact form -->     
        </tr>
<?php endif;?>
<?php get_footer(); ?
```

I want to turn my if statement above as a function something like but I don't know how:

```
        if(action_is_set()){
            then_do_the_action();
        }else {
            //begin content..etc.
        }
```

Is there a better structure of my code above??I'm still learning both PHP and Wordpress.
Please , please help. Thanks!!.

Comment: get 60% off on any theme you buy from mythemeshop..visit http://tech-papers.org/mythemeshop-coupon-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel it would be worth the effort to create a function action_is_set().

You would end up with:

```
function action_is_set() {
    return isset($_GET['action']);
}
```

Moving your switch to a function inside functions.php could be beneficial however.

That would look something similar to:

```
function do_action() {
    switch($_GET['action']) {
        case 'sendmail':
            include('sendmail.php');
            break;
    }
}
```

Or you can make this current page completely modular by moving the content section to a new include file:

```
<?php
get_header();

switch($_GET['action']) {
    case 'sendmail':
        include('sendmail.php');
        break;
    case 'mailsent':
        include('thanks.php');
        break;
    default:
        include('content.php');
}

get_footer();
?>
```

I don't know how this goes with the best practices for WordPress, but it is a good practice to have a default case in a switch especially in a scenario where it would do nothing if for instance they went to yourdomain.com/?action=blah

Rule of thumb: Never expect they will use it as intended; always assume that someone will try to break your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the function in functions.php under the theme.

Comment: @Dan This is nothing different from code normal function. You define some function in functions.php, and you can use them in your template php file. And also you can use add_action/add_filter to change the action of wordpress function like the_content.